# laravel 4: Route to controller when error occurred

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with `laravel 4`. I want to handle occurred errors like, `404 Not Found` or any other errors. But I want to call a controller when such errors occurs. I've tried this:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.404', array('error'=>$exception), 404);
});
```

But actually above code is not my purpose, I want something like this:

```
//I know this code doesn't work, I've just wanted to show the claim
App::missing('HomeController@error');
App::error('HomeController@error');
// or ...
```

Is there any way to handle errors within calling a specific controller's method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use `App::missing('Controller@method')` directly because the `missing` method calls `error` method and that is:

```
public function error(Closure $callback)
{
    $this['exception']->error($callback);
}
```

It accepts a closure but you may call a `controller`->`method` from the closure. So. declare the handler using a closure as usual and then call a controller's method from within the closure.

As a side note, I don't see any importance to call a method from a controller through/within the closure because you may do the same thing (most probably you'll return a view) from the closure then why just another layer ?

**Update:**

```
App::missing(function($e){
    // Use the model here you want
    $var = 'SomeValue' from model
    return Response::view('errors.404', array('error'=> $e, 'another' => $var));
});
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to pass some variables form model to that view. Do you have any suggestion or better solution to do this ?

Comment: You mean I directly write the `model` inside the `router.php` and don't pass it to `controller` ?

Comment: No, it's actually `global.php` where you keep (by default) your error handlers but you are free, it doesn't matter if you use any model here but if you are following the best practice then I would suggest you to create a repository class and use that.

Comment: May I ask you what data you want to pass to your error view from model ?

Comment: It's a variable contain menu items which is object exactly. I don't insist to use missing method. I prefer best simple solution.

Comment: Check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout#.U0Ek9fmSySo) for handling menu/nav bar smartly.

Comment: I'm using the `update code` which is working fine. But I'll read the article indeed. Thanks.

Comment: You may also check [laravel-repository-pattern](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern).

Answer (score 5):

Nothing's going to stop you from creating an instance of your controller and calling the method you want to call.

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return App::make('HomeController')->error($exception);
});
```

Comment: Pass the `$exception`, like `return App::make('HomeController')->error($exception);`.

Comment: I'm using this approach but if the request doesn't match any route, I get a 'Call to a member function filter() on a non-object' error ([details here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2861#issuecomment-53543679)). But If the request matches a route but no model is found (e.g. `firstOrFail()`) it works normally. Any idea?